# Java (Server)Socket multi room

Tags: java, sockets, socketserver

I am trying to find a way to create a multiroom Socket. So users can chat in different rooms or privately with other users. Is there a way to do this with the `java.net.Socket` and/or `java.net.ServerSocket`?

What is the best way to do this? Do I need to open a new port for each room and private chat?

I can see through my IDE that there is a Socket `getChannel()`, but unable to find anything about this.
Perhaps I am looking with the wrong words.

I hope someone can help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, there's a way to do it. You need to create a new Thread for every user that connect to your server and store the username and socket in a map<username,socket> then if someone wan't to send a message to specific user, you just pick up socket from a map and send a message to this user.

Simplest way to achieve a thread for all users looks like

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666);
        while (true){
            new User(serverSocket.accept()).start();
        }
```

Then you just need to ovveride run() method to monitor if user send any message to our server and pass it to a user witch is specified in message.

Comment: I basically have set this up already, but the idea with the map is great. If I want people to chat in rooms I could change the map to for example: map<username, socket, channelname>? and in the override of run  send to all threads with the same channelname?

Comment: Yea, sure but notice that map have only 2 parameters (Key,Value) so you cant add third one, if you wanna do this you need to create new Class with x,y,z Fields where at least one need to be a Socket so your map should looks like map<username,object> where object is the class you create to store information about socket and channel name, Hope this help you :)